# Lista de Niveles en Unity con C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d, script, unity

En el proyecto en el que trabajo (con Unity 2017.3) debo utilizar una sola escena para todos los niveles del juego. Cada nivel tiene su clase con su implementacion particular, pero todos ellos heredan de la clase Level.cs. Lo que necesito es almacenar los niveles de forma tal que lo que guarde en un archivo serializado sea unicamente un int de indice para ir a buscar el script del nivel en el que quedo el jugador.

Nivel base :

```
public class Level
{
public int id;
public string name;

public Level()
{

}

public void ConfigureLevel(StageObject stage)
{
    //some stuff
}}
```

Aqui un nivel particular :

```
public class Level_1: Level
{
int try= 0;

public Level_1(StageObject stage)
{
    base.id= 0;
    base.ConfigureLevel(stage);

}}
```

Aqui el levelmanager que deberia poder almacenar los niveles para luego con la data guardada instanciar el nivel actual y no el primero :

```
public class LevelManager : Singleton<LevelManager>
{
Level currentLevel;
Stage stage1, stage2, stage3;
void Start()
{
//load saved data and player prefs
currentLevel = new Level1(stage1); // For now I am always loading level 1,but I want to load the last one visited (the saved level)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un script en tiempo de ejecución con el código:
Solo tendrías que sustituir el agregar el script a cargarlo por su nombre en base al nivel guardado.

```
var scripts = Resources.LoadAll("Ubicación de script en carpeta resources", typeof(TextAsset)); 
foreach (TextAsset item in scripts) {//Agegamos los script al objeto que los debe contener, siempre será el main asset.
    gameObject.AddComponent (System.Type.GetType(item.name));
}
```

por ejemplo:

```
public class LevelManager : Singleton<LevelManager> {
   Level currentLevel;
   Stage stage1, stage2, stage3;
   void Start(){//load saved data and player prefs
      int savedLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LevelSaved");
      var script = Resources.Load("Scripts/Level_"+savedLevel, typeof(TextAsset));
      currentLevel = System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type.GetType(script)); // No estoy seguro que permita crear la instancia de la clase y aceptar parámetro, pero puedes checarlo....
      currentLevel.ConfigureLevel(stage1);//Tendrías que modificar el constructor y agregar el base.id en este método...  
   }
}
```